# I am getting error logical in method getData() in my Java homework

Tags: java, object

Here is my assignment:

> Create a class named TestLease whose main() method declares four Lease objects. Call a getData() method three times. Within the method, prompt a user for values for each field for a Lease, and return a Lease object to the main() method where it is assigned to one of main()’s Lease objects. Do not prompt the user for values for the fourth Lease object, but let it continue to hold the default values.
>
> Then, in main(), pass one of the Lease objects to the showValues() method that displays the data. Then call the addPetFee() method using the passed Lease object and confirm that the fee explanation statement is displayed. Next, call the showValues() method for the Lease object again and confirm that the pet fee has been added to the rent. Finally, call the showValues() method with each of the other three objects; confirm that two hold the values you supplied as input and one holds the constructor default values.

My results is correct as the homework requires. But my professor says that I have a logical error at getData() method. I tried to find the error but could not figure out.

```
class Lease {
    
    private String name;
    private int aptNumber;
    private double rent;
    private int term;
    
    private static final int FEE = 10;

    public Lease() {
        name = "XXX";
        aptNumber = 0;
        rent = 1000.0;
        term = 12;
    }
    
    public void setName(String tenant) {
        name = tenant;
    }

    public void setAptNumber(int apt) {
        aptNumber = apt;
    }

    public void setRent(double monthRent) {
        rent = monthRent;
    }

    public void setTerm(int t) {
        term = t;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAptNumber() {
        return aptNumber;
    }

    public double getRent() {
        return rent;
    }

    public int getTerm() {
        return term;
    }

    public void addPetFee() {
        rent = rent + FEE;
        explainPetPolicy();
    }

    public static void explainPetPolicy() {
        System.out.println("A pet fee of $10 is added to your monthly rent and: ");
    }
}


import java.util.Scanner;

class TestLease

{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
       Lease lease1 = getData();
       showValues(lease1);
       
       Lease lease2 = getData();
       showValues(lease2);
       
       Lease lease3 = getData();
       showValues(lease3);
       lease3.addPetFee();
       showValues(lease3);
       
       Lease lease4 = new Lease();
       showValues(lease4);
       
        }
   
   public static void showValues(Lease ls)
   {
      System.out.println("\n\nYour lease results:" +
         "\nName      : " + ls.getName() +
         "\nApartment : " + ls.getAptNumber() +
         "\nRent      : " + ls.getRent() +
         "\nTerm      : " + ls.getTerm() + "\n");
   }
   
   public static Lease getData()
   {
       Lease sample = new Lease();
       Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
       String sampleName = userInput.nextLine();
       sample.setName(sampleName);
       
       System.out.println("Please enter your apartment number:");
       int sampleAptNumber = userInput.nextInt();
       sample.setAptNumber(sampleAptNumber);
       
       System.out.println("Please enter your monthly rent amount:");
       double sampleRent = userInput.nextDouble();
       sample.setRent(sampleRent);

       System.out.println("Please enter the term of your lease in months:");
       int sampleTerm = userInput.nextInt();
       sample.setTerm(sampleTerm);
       userInput.nextLine();
       
       return sample;
   }
   
}
```

Comment: your userInput should not be a local variable, there's no need in creating a new one each time you call the method. You also don't need all those 'sampleName', 'sampleAptNumber' ... variables. but, "there is a logical error" is a bit vague if everything works as it should

Comment: Professor must be saying about error handling. You are accepting int & double but user might enter string which raises an exception.

Comment: @SurajKj that wouldn't be a logical error

Comment: @SurajKj It's so vague that I could not understand. Exception Handling is the new chapter that my class haven't reach yet.

Comment: Ask your teacher what they mean.